# How to consume lookaround in regex?

Tags: regex

I want to match
`abc_def_ghi`,
`abc_abc_ghi`,
`abc_a2a_ghi`,
`abc_999_ghi`
but not `abc_xxx_ghi` (with `xxx` in center).

I came up to manually consuming look ahead (`abc_(?!xxx)..._ghi`), but I wonder is there any other way without manually specifying number of characters to skip.

Original qustion was with numbers, updated for strings case.

Comment: You are not consuming lookaheads, you are using it. Probably you want to match digits only - `123_(?!000)\d{3}_789`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I mean skip characters it asserts

Comment: You cannot do that, as a regex cannot match and put into 1 group non-adjoining chunks of text within one match operation. Lookarounds are not meant to skip chars, they are meant to precise the context of a match or restrict a more generic pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to specify exactly how many characters to skip, perhaps you could use a quantifier like `+` in the negative lookahead and use a negated character class to match not an underscore.

```
\babc_(?!x+_)[^_]+_ghi\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\babc_` Word boundary, match abc_
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not

  - `x+_` Match 1+ times `x` followed by an underscore
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^_]+_` Negated character class, match 1+ times any char except `_`
- `ghi\b` Match ghi and word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZVjz9v/2)

Comment: fails with `abc_9x9_ghi`

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Then you might use a negative lookahead to assert not 1+ times x followed by an underscore. https://regex101.com/r/ZVjz9v/2

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use look-arounds, this expression might be an option:

```
(?:abc_xxx_ghi)|(abc_.{3}_ghi)
```

Other than that I can't think of anything else.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Un3cov/1/)

Comment: I knew that I missed something trivial.

Comment: sorry for changing question

Comment: @Emma It looks just the same as in my question (except `...` replace with `.*`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
123_(?:(?!000)\d){3}_789
```

[image]

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/UdwJeA/2/)

Comment: Not capturing group doesn't change matching logic here. It same as `123_(?!000)\d{3}_789`

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic this is the only way in regex to avoid a complete word as far as i know, if you really want to know alternate way is to match strings `abc_xxx_ghi` and filter the remaining one,

Comment: I was searching for a way without manually specifying number of characters to skip for example.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic we can use quantifier for that purpose you can replace `000` with `0+_`

Comment: `0+_` will match `123_000000_789`. I already specified in `(?!000)` that i don't want exactly three chars. Just want that look ahead consume(eat (skip)) chars it looking for